# ESP8266 boot message but no response to any AT commands (newest AT Firmware)

Tags: esp8266, uart, at-command, firmware

I´m trying to talk to my ESP8266-12F with a USB-Serial-adapter. I successfully flashed the newest firmware from Espressiv to the board using ESPTool. The flash and debug commands of esptool like `flash_id` work as expected with the esp in programming mode. I connected the board like down below.

```
ESP_RX -> TX
ESP_TX -> RX
EN -> 3.3V
RST -> Button to GND, pulled high
BOOT0 -> Button to GND, pulled high
GPIO15 -> GND
VCC -> 3.3V
GND -> GND
Power is supplied from the serial adapter
Logic Level is 3.3V on RX/TX
```

Firmware: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-at/en/release-v2.2.0.0_esp8266/AT_Binary_Lists/ESP8266_AT_binaries.html

When i power up or reset the esp i get the normal bootup message at 74880 baud.

```
 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

load 0x40100000, len 6960, room 16 
tail 0
chksum 0x4f
load 0x3ffe8008, len 24, room 8 
tail 0
chksum 0xc6
load 0x3ffe8020, len 3196, room 8 
tail 4
chksum 0x3a
csum 0x3a
```

Now when i try to send any AT command, i get no response (tried 9600, 19200, 74880, 115200 baud). I made sure to send `\r\n` with every command (selected CR&LF on Arduino Serial Monitor). The manual of the firmware expects 115200,8N1 for the uart communication but the esp doesn´t respond. I tried this with multiple modules to make sure this isn´t just a bad chip.

I´m frustrated and i dont really know what to try anymore to make this work. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: the AT 2 uses UART on alternative pins  for AT commands. pin 15 as TX and 13 as RX. (at 115200 baud). the AT 2 for esp8266 is very buggy. it is better to use AT 1.7.5 (from SDK 3.0.5)

Comment: The manal says that CTS/RTS are swapped with TX/RX for AT commands. While searching for the sdk i came accross the ai thinker version of the firmware. I works fine now. Thank you! I mark this as solved.

Comment: To mark the question as solved there needs to be an answer, however you are able to write an answer yourself and accept it.